# Reading PGP key information

Tags: public-key, openpgp, public-fields

can someone show a description of the information of what a pgp looks like if only the descriptions were there but not the actual information? something like (i dont remember if the values are correct)**:**

> packet-type[4 bits],
>   total length in bytes[16 bits],
>   packet version type [4 bits],
>   creation-time[32 bits],
>   encryption-algorithm[8 bits], ...,etc,etc

ive tried to understand rfc4880, but its tedious and confusing. so far, i am think i have extracted the 4 i wrote above, but i cant seem to get the rest of the information out.

can anyone help? i know i can just find some pgp program, but the whole point of this is to allow me to learn how those programs work in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully section 4.2 of RFC 4880, there different packet formats, with different packet length encodings.